# How to Find K3,3 and K5 configuration of nonplanar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

I need help with letter K and L..

I was able to do C like this:

Number of 3-degree vertices: 4 {b, c, d, f}
Number of 4-degree vertices: 5 {a, e, g, h, i}

For K5 configuration, we have a, e, g, h, i 
and when we form a graph using those vertices, we see that ag, ie, ha, and ge are not connected.
Thus, there is no K5 configuration.

For K3,3
I used vertices b, c, d, e, f and i and was able to get a k3,3 configuration.

Now the graph of k is tricky to me because it has 8 vertices and I do not know how to reconfigure it into K5 or k3,3....

Comment: Recall that Wagner's theorem says that a graph is planar iff it does not contain $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a minor.

Comment: Yes but how can i determine a K5 configuration for graph k?

Comment: Okay so I think the way I did it was over-complicated but for K5 I got, f-e-g-a-h-f with edges, fa, fg, he, hg, and ae

Comment: Actually, scratch my prior comments. I missed a missing edge. For (k), there is a $K_{3,3}$ using vertices $a,b,c,d,e,f$. One side of the bipartition is $\{a,c,e\}$, and the other is $\{b, d, f\}$. Again for (l) it is just contraction of edges to get the obvious $K_5$.

Comment: Your prior $K_5$ is not a $K_5$ since there is no edge from $a$ to $e$.

Comment: You've already solved it, but for graph $(k)$ my first instinct would be to do the obvious coloring on the vertices; if we color vertices alternately around the outside 8-cycle, then every 'inner' edge goes from a vertex of one color to a vertex of the other, so there's a clear bipartite division, and from there it's just a matter of finding a $K_{3,3}$ among the vertices.